Add the data series in charts based on column values Python
I am very new to the Python coding. I need some help on this code. I have this data which have many stages (starting from 0,1,2....8) and Node levels with respect to each nodes and the corresponding DISPLACEMENT, BM & SF.
So i want to plot 3 plots:

X = BM, Y = Node level
X = SF, Y = Node level
X = DISPLACEMENT, Y = Node level

So in each plot i have to add the stages as seriess. So all 3 plots will have the series based on the stage vales (such as Stage 0, Stage 1,......Stage 8).
Any possible codes or any source i can learn from will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.
The code i have prepared is below:
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

str_filename = 'results.csv'
fh = open(str_filename)
csv_reader = csv.reader(fh)

csv_header = next(csv_reader)
csv_header 

lst_fs = next(csv_reader)
np_d_fs = np.array(list(map(float, lst_fs)))
np_d_fs

fh.close()

df_sig = pd.read_csv(str_filename, header=None, skiprows=1, names=csv_header)
df_sig


So the data sample is below:
Stage,Node,Node level,Displacement,BM,SF
0,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,1,-0.13111111521720886,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,2,-0.2622222304344177,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,3,-0.3933333456516266,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,4,-0.5244444608688354,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,5,-0.6555555462837219,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,6,-0.7866666913032532,0.0,0.0,0.0
0,7,-0.9177777767181396,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,1,-0.13111111521720886,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,2,-0.2622222304344177,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,3,-0.3933333456516266,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,4,-0.5244444608688354,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,5,-0.6555555462837219,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,6,-0.7866666913032532,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,7,-0.9177777767181396,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,8,-1.048888921737671,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,9,-1.1800000667572021,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,10,-1.3111110925674438,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,11,-1.442222237586975,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,12,-1.5733333826065063,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,13,-1.7044445276260376,0.0,0.0,0.0
1,14,-1.8355555534362793,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,1,-0.13111111521720886,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,2,-0.2622222304344177,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,3,-0.3933333456516266,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,4,-0.5244444608688354,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,5,-0.6555555462837219,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,6,-0.7866666913032532,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,7,-0.9177777767181396,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,8,-1.048888921737671,0.0,0.0,0.0
2,9,-1.1800000667572021,0.0,0.0,0.0

Pandas and matplotlib i ahve tried.

It's recommended to remove all code concerning the csv library.  df_sig = pd.read_csv(str_filename) will do all these things automatically.  What is missing, is a good explanation of how exactly you want to plot these columns. Then, you can use df_sig['Stage'], df_sig['Node level']etc. as arrays (or series) to plot.
